# This SQL code goes slightly over my head

Tags: sql, execute

Can anyone please explain to me what the following SQL code does. I do apologize for my amateurish ignorance in advance...

```
DECLARE @SalesYTDBySalesPerson money;
EXECUTE AdventureWorks2016.Sales.uspGetEmployeeSalesYTD N'Blythe', @SalesYTD = @SalesYTDBySalesPerson OUTPUT; 
SELECT @SalesYTDBySalesPerson SalesYTDBySalesPerson
```

Comment: How slightly?  A hairs width?  An inch?  More than a foot?  I think over a foot is more than slightly.

Answer (score 1):

- The code declares a variable.
- Executes a stored procedure passing Blythe as variable to it and tells the procedure it wants to use the variable it declared on line 1 to retrieve the output of the procedure.
- Then it selects the output of the procedure and creates a column alias for it